# How to take a For Loop onto the GPU in Julia via CUDA

Tags: cuda, julia, gpu

I am new to looking at how to use the GPU for coding purposes.
I have seen CUDA with a Nvidia GPU.
My code on the CPU is an optimisation method with BlackBoxOptim.jl as follows:

```
px_values = collect(-4.5/ang:0.25/ang:4.5/ang)
py_values = collect(-4.5/ang:0.25/ang:4.5/ang)

min_energy_values = zeros(length(px_values),length(py_values))

for i in axes(px_values,1)
    Threads.@threads for j in axes(py_values,1)
                        px=px_values[i]
                        py=py_values[j]

                        f1 = (y) -> Hexpecvalue(px,py,y)./NormalWF(y)

                        result =bboptimize(f1,[1,0,5.0]; SearchRange=[(0,10),(1,10)],MaxFuncEvals=1250)

                        min_energy_values=best_fitness(result)
                    end
end
```

end

But I now want to be able to implement this over the GPU.

I have seen to begin with we have to introduce CUArryays, i.e like:

```
px_values = CUDA.CuArray(collect(-4.5/ang:0.25/ang:4.5/ang))
py_values = CUDA.CuArray(collect(-4.5/ang:0.25/ang:4.5/ang))
min_energy_values = CUDA.zeros(length(px_values), length(py_values)).
```

However, I am unsure how to begin fully setting up CUDA to enable me to do this.

Comment: try https://github.com/JuliaGPU/KernelAbstractions.jl

Comment: `py=px_values[i]` should be `py=py_values[j]`, I think.

Answer (score -1):

There are different options for this, and it's probably worth  it for you to look into a more general introduction on GPU programming (not just for Julia).

With regards to your question "How to take a For Loop onto the GPU in Julia via CUDA":  Generally, on GPU you'd want to avoid scalar indexing of your arrays, so regular for loops are usually not suitable.

- Try to formulate your problem in a way that can be solved directly in matrix form or with `map`, and doesn't need the `for` loop anymore.
- Look into libraries that provide macros that allow for more complex Tensor operations, Tullio.jl and TensorOperations.jl are both GPU compatible and you can use them to turn quite complicated operations into a one line command that works on both, CPU and GPU, they define the GPU kernels for you
- Write your own kernels with KernelAbstractions.jl or CUDA.jl

With regards to your code: It does look you are performing some kind of optimisation in the `for` loop on every element. Without a MWE or more context, it's very hard to tell if this is actually easy and efficient to run on GPUs or not, the optimisation would need to support GPUs as well or you would need to look for alternatives that are GPU-compatible. Try to formulate your problem as a **minimal, reproducible** example ([see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and you are more likely to get some more concrete help.

Comment: I also wonder. I edited my post to give it a bit more structure. OP is asking two different questions: "how to GPU-ify loops in Julia", "how does my code work on GPU", for the latter question there's some information missing and the code is not MWE.